# NFC Software developement kit NFC wrapper sample Code

Tags: c#, .net, nfc, ndef

When I Open the NFC wrapper sample codethe program works by stating "SCM_NFC.DLL successfully loaded". But when i tried debugging the code and place the card on the device. i am always getting MessageCount as Zero.

Can anyone tell me whats wrong?

Thanks in Advance

[image]

```
private void ReadNDEF() {   
    UInt32 DeviceCount = 0;
    UInt32 MessageCount = 0;
    UInt32 NextMessageSize = 0;
    UInt32 Result;

    if (NFCWrapper == null) return;

    // Get information about the message queue
    Result = TNFCWrapper.GetNDEFQueueInfo(ref DeviceCount, ref MessageCount, ref NextMessageSize);
    if (MessageCount != 0) {
        if (Result != TNFCWrapper.ERR_SUCCESS) return;

        //Resize the NDEF buffer accordingly to the site of the next message in the queue
        byte[] NDEF = new byte[NextMessageSize];
        UInt32 NDEFSize = NextMessageSize;
        TNFCAddress NFCAddress = new TNFCAddress();
        TMessageInfo MessageInfo = new TMessageInfo();

        //Read the NDEF message from the message queue
        Result = TNFCWrapper.ReadNDEF(ref NFCAddress, ref MessageInfo, ref NDEF[0], ref NDEFSize);
        if (Result != TNFCWrapper.ERR_SUCCESS) return;

        //Display the message details
        string sAddress = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) sAddress = sAddress + NFCAddress.Address[i].ToString("X2") + " ";

        PrintHexDump(NDEF, NDEFSize);

        // convert NDEF into XML
        string XML = "";
        Result = NFCWrapper.NDEF2XML(ref NDEF[0], NDEFSize, ref XML);

        if (Result != TNFCWrapper.ERR_SUCCESS) return;

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(XML);
        var valueRead = XElement.Parse(XML)
                   .Descendants("NDEF_Text")
                   .First()
                   .Value;
        string associateId = valueRead.Substring(5);
        LogMessage(associateId);
        NavigationService navService = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
        navService.Navigate(new System.Uri("Booking.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by the result of `GetNDEFQueueInfo()`, no devices and no NDEF messages were detected. Consequently, `ReadNDEF()` must fail as it can't read something that isn't there.

Without knowing how you initialized the NFC reader and what you programmed on the "card"/NFC tag, it is difficult to say what's going wrong, but here's a list of possible causes that come to my mind:

1. The NFC tag/"card" must contain a valid NDEF message.
2. You did not call `StartListening()` to activate scanning for NFC tags/NFC devices.
3. You previously disabled scanning for the tag type of your "card" using `SetTarget()`.